# pivot_table de frequencia

Tags: python, pandas, data, ciência-de-dados, pivot

Quero construir um pivot_table no pandas que conte a frequencia.
Por exemplo, tenho uma coluna sexo, com 2 opçoes, uma de UF, com 5 opçoes, e uma de cor, com 4 opçoes, queria fazer uma tabela que mostrasse quantas pessoas de x sexo e de y UF tem z cor, mas me encontro num looping de testar o cor como values e como columns mas sem achar nenhuma resposta.
(a aggfunc count não consegui utilizar desta forma)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que `groupby` com o `agg` seja a solução. Veja o exemplo:

### Carregando bibliotecas

```
import pandas as pd
import random
```

### Variáveis auxiliares

```
sexos = ["M", "F"]
ufs = ["BA", "ES", "MT", "RJ", "SP"]
cores = ["amarelo", "azul", "vermelho", "roxo", "verde"]

tamanho = 1000
```

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"sexo": [random.choice(sexos) for _ in range(tamanho)], "uf": [random.choice(ufs) for _ in range(tamanho)], "cor": [random.choice(cores) for _ in range(tamanho)]})
```

### Criando "pivot_table"

```
print(df.groupby(["sexo", "uf", "cor"]).agg({"cor": 'count'}))
```

O resultado será algo como abaixo:

```
                  cor
sexo uf cor
F    BA amarelo    21
        azul       20
        roxo       14
        verde      15
        vermelho   25
     ES amarelo    23
        azul       23
        roxo       22
        verde      24
        vermelho   25
     MT amarelo    24
        azul       19
        roxo       16
        verde      26
        vermelho   14
     RJ amarelo    14
        azul       20
        roxo       14
        verde      21
        vermelho   14
     SP amarelo    20
        azul       24
        roxo       17
        verde      18
        vermelho   14
M    BA amarelo    15
        azul       17
        roxo       24
        verde      22
        vermelho   30
     ES amarelo    14
        azul       19
        roxo       18
        verde      22
        vermelho   20
     MT amarelo    33
        azul       19
        roxo       15
        verde      18
        vermelho   22
     RJ amarelo    29
        azul       18
        roxo       20
        verde      19
        vermelho   19
     SP amarelo    17
        azul       22
        roxo       17
        verde      22
        vermelho   22
```